# How to receive notification when an NSView is moved

Tags: macos, user-interface, nsview

How to receive a notification/callback when a NSView is moved - alternatively when a NSViewController is moved.

I see that there are methods for NSWindow (NSWindowDidMoveNotification) but I cannot find out how handle it with an NSView or NSViewController.

I understand that NSView has a NSWindow and that this is what has 'a coordinate' but I'm not sure how to subclass this NSWindow to overwrite the move method.

Answer (score 2):

I found out. Add an observer like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(frameDidChange:)
                                                name:NSViewFrameDidChangeNotification
                                              object:self.view];
```

And a selector like this:

```
- (void)frameDidChange:(NSNotification*)notification {

   NSView* view = [notification object];

   ...
}
```